# microsoft partner center api requirements

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-partnercenter-java

If you had an experience with ms partner center, I'm trying to access the api.

So far I have only succeeded to make api requests if the mspc user is a Global administrator, but I feel that there must be another way.

Do you know(can you advice me some resources) how can I access api with the user which is not global admin ?

I have tried to do it with the referral admin but no luck there, I can only access web portal, but not api.

Thanks.

Comment: Any updates? I am not able to access the API at all.

Comment: @amo Yes, it's working for me now. As I remember the issue was caused because of the grant_type parameter that I attached to the request. I have not posted it because I don't remember it exactly